# Wait for class variable to change using threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a class that contains a boolean variable and a function that waits for the boolean to change in order to execute some code. Some (rather silly) example:

```
import time

class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = False

    def setVar(self, state):
        self._var = state

    def waitForVarToChange(self):
        while not self._var:
            continue

        print 'Variable changed'
        self._var = False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myclass = SomeClass()

    while True:
        myclass.waitForVarToChange()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        myclass.setVar(True)
```

In this example the `waitForVarToChange()` method will obviously get stuck in the while loop while 'waiting' for the variable to change. From what I now, I should use *threads* and/or *events* here. However, I have no idea what is the nicest way to implement a thread for such kind of example. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you really need threads? Why not do your action directly in `setVar`?

Comment: The problem is a little bit more complex. The actual class is a 3D renderer. One can obtain a frame from the class using a `getFrame()` method. The method should only return a frame if a _new_ frame is available. Hence, if the variable is set to `True` a new frame is available. Otherwise the `getFrame()` method should wait until the new frame is available and then fetch it.

Comment: @HGM Then don't use a flag but a `Queue.Queue` to communicate between threads. The renderer puts finished frames into the queue and the other thread gets them from the queue, blocking if necessary waiting for a frame to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `multiprocessing` and `Queue`s like @BlackJack suggested.  It's easier to work with, especially the `Pool` object.

Here's a multithreading solution. One thread starts, waits for a while, then flags a thread-safe `Event` object.  A second thread was waiting for the `Event`, which after the event is set, prints a message and exits.

### source

```
import threading, time


def flagger_thread(event):
    time.sleep(2)
    event.set()

def waiter_thread(event):
    print("Waiting for event")
    if event.wait(5):
        print("event set.")
    else:
        print("Timed out.")

stop_event = threading.Event()
threading.Thread(target=flagger_thread, args=[stop_event]).start()
threading.Thread(target=waiter_thread, args=[stop_event]).start()

for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t != threading.current_thread():
        t.join()
```

### output

```
Waiting for event
event set.
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified your code a little bit for my purposes, but now it works!